# repeated firebase deploy functions pub/sub creates duplicate scheduler jobs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-scheduler

I use the following command to deploy my project, one of the functions being a pub/sub:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

...and everything happens just fine, but the scheduler job is created a 2nd time, an exact copy of the previous one every time I deploy again.

I don't change the pub/sub function, so I would not necessarily need to include it during deploy, but why is it creating a new scheduler job every time? Neither the function, nor the topic in Pub/Sub is duplicating, only the scheduler job - why?

Here is how the pubsub function looks like, if relevant:

```js
export const scheduledStuff = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('0 0 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York')
  .onRun(() => {
    // do stuff
  })
```

*Update Jun 17 2022:* I didn't specifically mention this, but the code I gave above, I hoped, should have given it away: I'm using the ES6 annotation for the function, ie. use `import` instead of `require` for packages, and the function is exported as `export const scheduledStuff...` instead of `exports.scheduledStuff...`.

My functions are then separated into 2 categories, `functions:functions`, which are all the functions that are NOT pubsub, and this one pubsub. This is because I wanted to prevent the deployment of the pubsub function to my staging environment, so I'm using `firebase deploy --only functions:functions` for that one.

For this purpose I have an index file in my main functions directory that looks something like this:

```js
import { default as firstFunction } from './callables/firstFunction.js'
import { default as secondFunction } from './callables/secondFunction.js'
//...

export const functions = {
    firstFunction,
    secondFunction,
    //...
}

import { scheduledStuff } from './pubsub/scheduledStuff.js'

export const pubSubStuff = { scheduledStuff }
```

Comment: Try changing the timezone from the above to America/New_York. 
This seems to be an issue with the writing the checking here, when specifying an incorrect time zone (omitted the underscore), it can happen that the scheduled function is deployed but the timezone is incorrect and which in turn can lead to odd behavior like this. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#write_a_scheduled_function )

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra I actually made a typo in the question (corrected now), it’s a different time zone in my code (and it’s 100% correct), so that’s definitely not the route of the problem, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your case by deploying the below scheduler function which will run every minute and create a pubsub topic and a scheduler job.
[image]
[image]

In my case, my first deploy `firebase deploy –only functions` created a pubsub topic **firebase-schedule-scheduledFunctionCrontab-us-central1** and a scheduler job **firebase-schedule-scheduledFunctionCrontab-us-central**.

[image]
With the second deployment `firebase deploy –only functions`, neither a  duplicate scheduler job was created nor a duplicate  pubsub topic.

My terminal shows the below lines:

```
functions: updating Node.js 16 function scheduledFunctionCrontab(us-central1)...
✔ functions[scheduledFunctionCrontab(us-central1)] Successful update operation.
```

The last deployment run got updated but a duplicate is not created. Also the scheduler function keeps updating the last run time  and next run time field which confirms that the function is running every minute.

If what you have shared here, is the entire code of your scheduler function, then I think this is a Customer issue/bug.
Still to confirm I would like to have a look at your logs, but if you are confident that this is not an intended behavior (which seems to be according to me) please [raise a support ticket with Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support)  or [raise a Customer issue in a public issue tracker](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs)

Comment: Thanks for this, I really appreciate you taking the time and testing this. There is just one thing I didn't specifically mention in my question, but the code I gave at the end, I hoped, should have given it away: I'm using the ES6 annotation for the function, ie. use `import` instead of `require`, and the function is exported as `export const scheduledStuff...` instead of `exports.scheduledStuff...`. Could that be the problem? I wonder... I'll update the original question with details...

Comment: I updated my question with details. As this is only happening in production, and I don't plan any deployment there right now, it may take me a while before I can collect logs for the next run, but I will (either here or a support ticket).